# iPhone: How to get the contents of the documents directory as a NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

How do I get the contents of the documents directory as a NSMutableArray?

I can get it as a normal NSArray, but as soon as I try to do anything with that array, my app crashes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. But you can easily create a mutable array from a non-mutable one:

```
NSMutableArray* mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: someOtherArray];
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will work:  `NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL] mutableCopy];`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you might be allocating the array incorrectly.  Can you attach some code samples of your creation of the `NSMutableArray` instance and then how you are inserting elements into that mutable array?